# MainApp send to page depending on value

Tags: dart, flutter

I am building a Flutter app and when the app starts I want to send the user to either the login page (if not yet logged in) or the Dashboard page (if logged in).

Basically, the main() will just be code, no widgets. How would I accomplish this?

Im imagining something like:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new StarterPoint()
  ));
}

class StarterPoint extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool loggedIn = false;

    if (loggedIn) {
      Navigator.push(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Dashboard()),
      );
    } else {
            Navigator.push(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()),
      );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example of what you could do. I think you need to keep track of state in StarterPoint depending on whether or not you are logged in.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: StarterPoint()));
}

class StarterPoint extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => StarterPointState();
}

class StarterPointState extends State<StarterPoint> {
  bool loggedIn = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (loggedIn) {
      return Dashboard();
    } else {
      return Login(() => setState(() {
            loggedIn = true;
          }));
    }
  }
}

class Dashboard extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text('hello!');
  }
}

class Login extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function() callBack;
  Login(this.callBack);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      RaisedButton(child: Text('press'), onPressed: () => callBack())
    ]);
  }
}
```